# Unable to rescale an image using transforms.Resize

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to rescale an image of size 255, 255 having 5 channels to something more manageable for my CNN, i.e 5, 40, 40

Here is a minimally reproducible example -

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torchvision as TV
from torchvision import transforms
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(5,255,255)
transform = TV.transforms.Resize([transforms.Scale(48)])
transform(torch.from_numpy(x))
```

But I get the following error -

```
 File "C:\Users\thoma\anaconda3\envs\tf-latest\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py", line 186, in __init__                                                                                      assert isinstance(size, int) or (isinstance(size, Iterable) and len(size) == 2)                     AssertionError
```

Comment: `transform = TV.transforms.Resize((48,48))` seems to work with `TV` version 0.8.2, torch version 1.7.1

Comment: @QuangHoang I get the following error then - TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>

Comment: Like I said, works on my specific settings. You can pass `PIL.from_array(x)` or something similar instead of `torch.from_array` if that's the error.